# ffmpeg Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg -i '

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Hi everyone i try to mirror my video file i use this library for ffmpeg

compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

and this is my commande :

uriPathOut = getInternalDirectoryPath() + "/Movies/3.mp4";
 uriPathIn = getInternalDirectoryPath() + "/Movies/1.mp4";

cmd = new String[]{"ffmpeg -i",uriPathIn," -vf \"vflip\" -metadata:s:v rotate=180 ",uriPathOut};

and i always get this error :

'[NULL @ 0xb84192d0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg -i'
 ffmpeg -i: Invalid argument'

is there any solution help me please.

Answer (score 3):

There is no command named "`ffmpeg -i`". You need to run "`ffmpeg`" with separate "`-i`" and other arguments.

```
cmd = new String[] {
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i", uriPathIn,
    "-vf", "vflip",
    "-metadata:s:v", "rotate=180",
    uriPathOut
};
```

Comment: I just removed "ffmpeg" and it works thank you very much ephemient

Comment: Great solution @ephemient